# IPhone X Swiping up to switch app activates buttons at the bottom of the screen

Tags: gesture, ios11

We are currently checking if our app is compatible with the upcoming iPhone X and its new form factor and gestures. 
We noticed a problem regarding the switch to home screen gesture where swiping up actually triggers the action on the buttons located at the bottom of the screen.

In our case, this is problematic, because our app is a remote controller for very high end amplifiers and the buttons located at the bottom of the screen are volume buttons..

See image:

[image: Figure 1]

Anyone here had to deal with this kind of issue lately?

I was thinking of some kind of event that could be triggered by the swipe up gesture and disabling the buttons maybe?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not first move the bottom buttons above the home indicator? You might solve your UI and UX problem with one fix.

Comment: Yep, we thought about it but the swipe goes further than the indicator and the button would have to be too far away from the edge.

Comment: I would suggest trying to move the buttons first. Your UI is currently broken, and needs to be fixed anyways. In other apps (like those with tabs near the home indicator), buttons near the bottom are not activated when the home swipe gesture has begun.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your help, we did as you suggested. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we finally decided to go for the safe area principle and stick our bottom bar to the bottom of the safe area as suggested by Apple.

It's a bit annoying as it adds a big empty space at the bottom of the screen but I guess every app having actions there will have the same problem (tab bar for example)

[image: Safe area]

Here's the article I used:
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/

If you found another solution, I would be happy to read about it.

Thanks.

Comment: That looks good! Glad it worked. The "big empty space at the bottom of the screen" is intentional, as it gives the user space to perform home indicator actions like going home and switching between apps. I personally think it looks really good.